# why doesn't D3.layout.force doesn't start properly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am creating a graph using d3's layout.force engine for a force-directed graph layout.

For a while it was working, but now when I execute the `start()` function nothing happens. I've stripped my code down to the following:

```
    var svg = d3.select("#field_d3").append("svg");
    var width = 720;
    var height = 640;
    svg.attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    var nodes = [
        {nid: "node1", x: width/2, y: height/2},
        {nid: "node2", x: width/2, y: height/2},
        {nid: "node3", x: width/2, y: height/2}
    ];

    var links = [
        { source: 0, target: 1},
        { source: 1, target: 2}];

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .size([width, height])
        .linkStrength(0.9)
        .friction(0.9)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .charge(-30)
        .gravity(0.1)
        .alpha(0.2);

    console.log("Force layout initilized", force);
    force.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Force Layout calculations complete");
    });

    force.on('start', function () {
        console.log("Force layout started");
    });

    force.on('tick', function () {
        console.log("Force layout is ticking");
    });

    console.log("Starting force layout", force);
    force.start();
    //------------
    console.log("Now after all force layout code");
```

field_d3 is a div with id=field_d3.

But all I see in the console is

```
Force layout initilized Object {}
Starting force layout Object {}
Now after all force layout code
```

With none of the start, end, or tick functions being called.
What is going wrong?

Comment: @echonax The snippet provided is a very good example for a [mcve]; it's  stripped down to the bare minimum and contains all the code it needs to tackle the problem at hand. The circles and lines are just graphical representations of the calculated values and are not essential to this problem. The same holds true for the `tick()` function, which for this question won't need to be any more verbose than writing a log. Kudos to @GreySage who made the effort to provide a good example. Although it should preferably have been put into an executable Stack Snippet, a JSFiddle or the like ;-)

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843476/why-doesnt-d3-layout-force-doesnt-start-properly#comment63165649_37843476) said, it perfectly works for me if I put the code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3et3aee6/). All logs from the `start`, `tick` and `end` functions are printed as expected.

Comment: @altocumulus Oh I'm sorry I haven't read the question that carefully. I thought OP meant that nothing is appearing on the screen but actually was asking about the force functions :)

Answer (score 0):

You've stripped out setting the values of width and height, which is stopping the force layout running (they'll both be undefined). It works when you stick them back in. e.g.

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw2z814e/

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I actually have set those variables, I just didn't include it in the code since it was up higher than everything else. I'll edit my question.